# How cypress can be integrated with Xray in Jira

Tags: cypress, jira-xray, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

We are using XRAY in our Jira instance for running so far manual test and record metrics for our QA department.
We would like now to move a step further in order to implement Test Automation integrated with X-ray.
X-ray can use cucumber syntax for test case

What is the way to integrate Cypress with X-ray ?

1. How can we create automation test in Jira and send them to Cypress ?
2. How to get cypress test result back to X-ray for reporting and tracking ?

We are new to cypress and automation test using those environment, thanks for sharing your findings

regards

Comment: Xray provides API that can be used for fetching and setting data. See https://docs.getxray.app/site/xray

Answer (score 3):

If using Cypress, you can use the report produced by the test runner to integrate with Xray. If you're using Cucumber together with Cypress, you'll use "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor" package; you'll need to decide which [workflow](https://docs.getxray.app/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=62267221#TestinginBDDwithGherkinbasedframeworks(e.g.Cucumber)-Workflows) to adopt - in other words, you need to decide which will be the master for editing/managing your Gherkin specification.
The flows are slightly different depending on that.

[This tutorial](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Testing+using+Cypress+and+Cucumber+in+JavaScript) details the two flows; it is for Xray on Jira Cloud but it can easily be adapted if you are using Jira on-premise (server/Datacenter).